# Drupal 9.5.10 - Entire site UI is broken giving PluginNotfoundException in watchdog CLI logs

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

The site is totally broken and I cant access any of the pages, not even the index page.

I am getting the following error (fetched from watchdog CLI).

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "block_page" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\Display\VariantManager are:  in
                                                 Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).
```

AND

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "string" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\Display\VariantManager are:  in
                                                 Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).
```

Key thing to note is that the **$definitions** passed to the **doGetDefinition** function is empty as can be seen from the error display. I had installed *password_policy* module intially but uninstalled and removed the folder(s) since. I know something is corrupted in the DB, but how do I fix it? I kow this because when I retors an oldcopy of the DB, the UI and everything works just fine. But since it's an old copy of the DB, I can't use it.

The UI is broken so I all URLs return

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

But the module I created for JSON APIs works well. So, only the UI is broken.

Any and all suggestions are welcome.